# Why am I getting a Mongoose error when making a PUT request to an empty route?

Tags: express, mongoose, axios

I have this function which makes an axios put request to `/api/lyric/tag`

```js
const addTag = async (name, tagId, lyricId) => {
    const body = {name, tagId, lyricId};
    await axios.put(`/api/lyric/tag`, JSON.stringify(body), { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} });
}
```

At the current moment the route `/api/lyric/tag` is completely empty:

```js
// @route   PUT api/lyric/tag
// @desc    Add tag to lyric
// @access  Private
router.put('/tag', auth, async (req, res) => {


});
```

Yet for some reason I get this error each time axios makes the put request:
`Cast to ObjectId failed for value "tag" at path "_id" for model "lyric"`

Am I losing my mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put res.send("OK") or res.json({ message: "OK" }) in the end of the route.

You are receiving this error because your are not responding the requester.

Or this route is matching another route...

/api/lyric has any route? If it's has, somewhat equal /api/lyric/:_id, this route it's invoked.

Try change the route to /api/lyric/tag/update. It is not REST but your route will be call. Then you will need refactore the api to be cohesive.

Comment: Yes thank you! I had the route `/api/lyric/:_id`. I will accept answer in 2 minutes.